# Is it possible to pass argument by name in TCL procedure?

Tags: function, variables, arguments, tcl, procedure

I have the following procedure:

```
proc test {a {b 10} {c 30}} {
    puts "$a $b $c"
}
```

I would like to call the test procedure by passing value to argument a and c and keep the default value of the argument b. In other words, I want to pass arguments value by name.

Is it possible to do it in TCL?

Answer (score 2):

No.

The usual method to do this is:

```
proc test { args } {
  # set up the defaults
  set a(-a) {}
  set a(-b) 10
  set a(-c) 30
  
  set len [llength $args]
  # some basic argument checking
  if { $len > 6 || $len < 2 || $len % 2 != 0 } {
    error "Invalid arguments"
  }
  array set a $args
  ...
}

set result [test -a 3 -c 40]
```

Comment: This is correct. The `tcl::prefix` command can be used to do a more sophisticated version of this. And people have argued for _years_ about how to do bind-by-name calling, but never has a conclusive answer been reached; it's tricky to balance all the different requirements right.